# How to make sure bots won't create many users on my app?

Tags: android, security

I have an android app that communicates with a server. The app when run for the first time will send a post request to `/user/register_device` and then the server will create a new user with random id and random key and returns the response

```
{
  "status": "success", 
  "data": {
    "uid": "sfasdfas2487329rhsdifasor092u403p8412jelfjsakl;dfajs09204u12341", 
    "ukey": "fs04932u401923u4jweofksa;ldfajs9-24-341243fasdfasdffdsafasfasfsafrweqrqgq4234fdsfasdfa34123"
  }
}
```

But now if an attacker makes a script that just send post requests to `/user/register_device` in a loop, he can create many users in the server. This will soon fill up the table with invalid users. So how to stop this?

Should I restrict the number of requests coming from an IP? Or should i add a secret_key into the android app and make app send this key too when registering_device? Are there any other methods to stop this?

Comment: This is nice question, if you use key here then hacker can do reverse engineering of your apk then get secret key then again hacker can start to create invalid users .

Answer (score 0):

Restricting by IP address may affect the functionality since many organisations use NAT scheme to hide internal IP addresses.

my suggestions
1. Use Captcha 
2. Double opt-in. When someone signs up through a subscribe form an email is immediately sent to the address they provided. 
3. create a unique key per user based on MAC address if the key appears again you should ignore it.
4. Put a checkbox "I'm human" 
http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-slider-captcha-wins/
5. Use SMS for verication

Comment: But my app has no login/signup option. I want the user not to go through that step since it adds complexity for user experience. But I also want to uniquely identify each app installations in android devices.

Comment: In this case, you can read device MAC or create unique key and store it in the device, then run HMAC (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HmacUserAuthentication) , on the server side save the key and prevent using it again.